# How do I get abstract methods from my superclass in the mtl language

Tags: acceleo, abstract-methods

I'm using Acceleo-MTL to generate Java classes. How do I get all my abstract methods from my abstract superclass?

To get simple operations and interfaces, I use this:

```
[comment]Operators[/comment]
[for (o : Operation | class.getOperations())]
[o.generateOperation()/]
[/for]

[comment]Interface Methods[/comment]
[for (interf : Interface | class.getImplementedInterfaces())]
[for (o : Operation | interf.ownedOperation)]
[o.generateInterace()/]
[/for]
[/for]
```

Does there exist a getter Method for Abstract methods like you have `getImplementedInterfaces()` for Interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your metamodel and how to navigate it. IIRC, `Class.getImplementedInterfaces()` is something that comes from UML, so I'll assume that's what you're using.

Furthermore, what you seem to be trying to do is "retrieve all operations for a given classifier, including inherited ones". There should never be any reason to navigate upon the super-classes and interfaces hierarchy yourself for such needs. In UML, this is done through `Classifier.getAllOperations()`, which means that you can do everything through :

```
[for (o : Operation | class.getAllOperations())]
[o.generateOperation()/]
[/for]
```

If you absolutely need to iterate over the interfaces and super-class(es) yourself, remember that you need to recursively navigate the whole hierarchy : the super-classes and interfaces of your class, the super-classes and interfaces of the super classes of your class, the super-classes ... until the root(s) of the inheritance tree. You'll also have to handle UML's multiple inheritance capabilities and thus solve the potential ambiguities it brings. For that, you'll need to familiarize yourself with the UML model. For instance, retrieving the super-classes is done through `Class.getSuperClasses()`. Determining if one of these super-classes is abstract is done through `Class.isAbstract()`... and so on.

A side note that could help you : you can import the UML metamodel in your workspace to have a quick overview of its concepts and how to navigate through it. For this :

- Use `File > Import...`
- In the pop-up, navigate to `Plug-in Development > Plug-ins and fragments` and hit `Next`
- Nothing to change on this page, hit `Next` a second time
- In the filter area, enter `org.eclipse.uml2.uml`
- Double-click `org.eclipse.uml2.uml` in the left panel so that it appears in the right one.
- Hit `Finish`

You now have a new project in your workspace, named `org.eclipse.uml2.uml`. You can open the `org.eclipse.uml2.uml\model\uml.ecore` file to see the UML metamodel.